# IIS rewrite rules to enforce HTTPS and one of several canoncial domains

Tags: iis, http-redirect, url-rewrite-module

The site I'm looking after has multiple canoncial domains - e.g.

```
example.com
example.com.au
example.co.nz
```

as well as some 'other' domains that need to be redirected to one of the canoncial domains (e.g. `example.us` should go to `example.com`).

All sites should be accessed via HTTPS

Is it possible to write a concise rule for each canoncial domain that redirects the user to that domain iff

- They're not on the canoncial domain (e.g. `www.example.com`, `example.us`) OR
- The connection is not HTTPS

I think I can see how to do it wih multiple rules, but it will quickly become fiddly (so concise rules would be nicer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it with the following (shoved multiple variables into the `input` with a `#` delimter):

```
<rule name="Redirect to example.co.nz" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions  logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTPS}#{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(^OFF)|(^.*#www\.)" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?example.co.nz$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.co.nz/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```